# Finding covariance of joint variables

Tags: probability

I'm given an equation
$$ f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = \{k \ \ \ \ \ (x,y) \in T, \ \ 0 \ \ \ \ \ otherwise.$$
where $$ T = \{(x,y) : x > 0, y > 0, x + y < 9\} $$

I'm trying to find $ \mathit cov(X,Y) $ which I know is $E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$

I tried calculating $E[X] $ by $$ \int_0^{9-x} x\frac{2(9-x)}{81} \ dx$$
and $E[Y]$ the same method but just symbols changed.

Tried $E[XY]$ by
$$ \int_0^x x(\int_0^{9-x} \frac{2y}{81} \ dy)dx$$ and so on solved it.

All of these gave me a really big fractions like
$E[X] = \frac{x^3-243x+1458}{243}$ I feel like I'm going completely off track.

Comment: $EX,EY, EXY$ are not variables. They cannot involve $x$. It helps to draw a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T=\{(x,y): 0<x<9, 0< y<9-x\}$ so $EX=\int_0^{9} \int_0^{9-x}x k dydx$. Similarly, $EY=\int_0^{9} \int_0^{9-x} y k dydx$ and $EXY=\int_0^{9} \int_0^{9-x} xy k dydx$. I will let you carry out the integrations.